# Add Two Integer Arrays into One Integer Array

Tags: java, arrays, addition

I am looking to take two arrays of Integers and add them together, but I am having some difficulty with the carrying bit.

```
public static int [] add(int [] a, int [] b) 
{
    int col = 0;
    int carry = 0;           
    int[] totalArray = new int[MAX_DIGITS + 1];           
    for(int i = MAX_DIGITS - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        col = a[i] + b[i] + carry; 
        if(col >= 10) {
            carry = col / 10; 
            totalArray[i] %= 10; 
        } else {
            totalArray[i] = col;
            carry = 0; 
        }
    }
    totalArray[0] = carry; 
    return totalArray;      
}
```

The above code adds 204 + 435 correctly but fails to add 22 + 3122 + 12 correctly (ouputs 65).
I have written other methods to make sure all of the digits are properly indexed within the array and have tested those methods. Seeing as it works for 204 + 435 but not the other, I can't see what's tripping me up. I do not want to use the BigInteger class - before anyone suggests I should.

Given int[]a [0000000000000000000000999] and int[]b [0000000000000000000000483] currently add(a,b) returns [0000000000000000000001000]

Comment: How are you adding 3 values when your method only takes 2 parameters?

Comment: I suggest writing some tests and adding them to your question, so that we can see exactly what data you are using.

Comment: @tgdavies done!

Comment: What is  the value of `MAX_DIGITS`?  Also, `for(int i = MAX_DIGITS - 1; i > 0; i--)` should be `...i>=0...` (you do want to examine the first digit, don't you?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine.  Just make certain that all your arrays only occupy locations `1 thru MAX_DIGITS-1` with actual values. This allows for carries into `totalArray[0]`.

```
static int MAX_DIGITS = 6;

int[] a = {0,0,0,0,2,2};
int [] b = {0,0,3,1,2,2};
int [] c = {0,0,0,0,1,2};

int[] part1 = add(a,b);
int [] total = add(part1, c);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(total));
```

Prints

```
[0, 0, 3, 1, 5, 6]
```

- All I did was reduce the size of the `totalArray` array to `MAX_DIGITS`
- and change the `i > 0` to `i >= 0` in the loop.
- ensure that `index 0` was `0` in all the arrays.
- the rest was your code.

```
public static int[] add(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int col = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    int[] totalArray = new int[MAX_DIGITS];
    for (int i = MAX_DIGITS-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        col = a[i] + b[i] + carry;
        if (col >= 10) {
            carry = col / 10;
            totalArray[i] %= 10;
        } else {
            totalArray[i] = col;
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    totalArray[0] = carry;
    return totalArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing, and while that is a valid point, that was not the problem. It only breaks when it has to carry a digit

Comment: Since totalArray is  one larger than the argument arrays shouldn't you be adding 1 to the totalArray index?  I made the change and it worked for me.

Comment: turns out I actually did not to add one to the total array, rather I changed the initialization of the total array to int[] totalArray = new int[MAX_DIGITS]; The problem was in if(col >= 10) when I did totalArray[i] %= 10; it should have been totalArray[i] = col % 10;